# What is the command to know the Kubernetes Pod running status?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create the containers, when i am trying to build it, it is going into failed state so how can i see the kube pod status in running status and would like to know the root cause of it. Why is it not getting success

Answer (score 0):

## Get the logs for the pod

```
kubectl logs -f <pod_name> -n <namespace>
```

## Get the list of events and other information for the pod

```
kubectl describe po <pod_name> -n <namespace>
```